# Updating font in label object

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, uifont

I'd like to change the `fontName` in `UILabel` Object inside the code.
I used:

```
myLabel.font.fontName = "Arial"
```

How can I fix it, in case I want to give the user the capability to update it? I had this in mind:

```
var fontByUser: String
myLabel.font.fontName = fontByUser
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
myLabel.font = UIFont(name: fontByUser, size: 14)
```